# Cisco Network ACL on ASA

Tags: router, cisco-asa

We have the following access list on our router:

```
access-list 101 permit ip 10.16.43.0 0.0.0.255 172.50.0.0 0.0.127.255
```

Traffic from our router flows through our Cisco ASA. I have been told that I need to create an access list on the ASA that is the reverse of the access list on our router above, I created the following:

```
access-list 101 extended permit ip 172.50.0.0 255.255.128.0 10.16.43.0 255.255.255.0
```

But that I have been told that's incorrect. Can someone let me know what it should be?

Comment: Perhaps it is because your are using the same ACL number? Maybe the intent was to have a different ACL. Extended ACLs should be placed as close to the source as possible, so ACL 101 will be on the interface for network `110.16.43.0/24`, but the reverse ACL should be on the interface for the network `172.50.0.0/17`, so it should be a different ACL (102?).

Comment: We need much more info. Start with a topology please. Is the router on the inside or outside of the asa? Where is the 10.16 network and where is the 172.50 network? From which of the 2 networks will traffic originate? Why do you have an acl on your router if the traffic passes through the asa?

Comment: And... since reverse ACLs are required for vpn,  you're not talking about a vpn tunnel between the router and the asa, are you?

Comment: Are you getting confused between reversing the wild card to subnet? Since ASA doesn't use wild cards maybe that's what they meant. You just have to reverse the wild card to subnet

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are allowing 172.50.0.0/17 full access to 10.16.43.0/24

If that was your intention then this is all good

Not sure why you should do the reverse?

Comment: Thanks corresponding, I thought it was correct too, but I'm being told that the acl on the ASA needs to be the reverse to allow return traffic. The acl number has no bearing.

Comment: ok wait, what ACL are you talking about? I usually have an ACL inbound on the outside interface for my incoming traffic and one inbound on my inside interface for my outgoing traffic.

When you allow something from outside to the inside this connection will be statefully allowed which means that this traffic won't be blocked going back

For you it is important to know from where the traffic originates and what ACLs are in the way

Comment: Mike, I'm talking about the acl on the ASA

Comment: Traffic is coming from the router - access-list 101 permit ip 10.16.43.0 0.0.0.255 172.50.0.0 0.0.127.255

Comment: @Carltonp I know that. :) Look, you don't need to have the ACL in reverse. What you have looks good. The ASA is stateful so your connection will be allowed both ways. The best is to just test this and have monitor logging on level 4 or 3 enabled so you can see dropped packets. Logging tells you which acl drops the packet so you can fix it quickly

Answer (score 1):

On ASAs, some ACL rules will implicitly allow **returning traffic**.  These rules only need to define a single direction of traffic.  The *CLI Book 2: Cisco ASA Series Firewall CLI Configuration Guide, 9.7* call out distinctions.

> **Extended Access Rules for Returning Traffic**
>
> For TCP, UDP, and SCTP
> connections for both routed and transparent mode, you do not need an
> access rule to allow returning traffic because the ASA allows all
> returning traffic for established, bidirectional connections.
>
> For connectionless protocols such as ICMP, however, the ASA
> establishes unidirectional sessions, so you either need access rules
> to allow ICMP in both directions (by applying ACLs to the source and
> destination interfaces), or you need to enable the ICMP inspection
> engine. The ICMP inspection engine treats ICMP sessions as
> bidirectional connections. For example, to control ping, specify
> echo-reply (0) (ASA to host) or echo (8) (host to ASA).

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa97/configuration/firewall/asa-97-firewall-config/access-rules.html#ID-2124-0000000

If your example ACL was on an ASA, you would still be required to explicitly define the reverse traffic because the protocol, `ip`, is stateless.

Router Extended ACLs do not have notion of statefulness.  The reverse/returning traffic must be explicitly defined. An exception to this rule is "Reflexive ACLs" and are outside the scope of this post.

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/security/configuration/guide/fsecur_c/scfreflx.html

Comment: Allowing IP still treats TCP, UDP as stateful traffic and the inspections still work for ICMP. It's only for other IP traffic that explicit rules would be required for return traffic.  Im not sure I've ever defined any such return rules except for RPC